# Sort items of list into sequential lists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list of messages from a machine, these events have a speed value and a timestamp. Using the speed value, I can determine if the machine was running or not. I want to sort the items of that list into sequential lists.

Let's take this original list of items as an example:

1. speed: 90; timestamp: 12:00
2. speed: 80; timestamp: 12:01
3. speed: 80; timestamp: 12:02
4. speed: 90; timestamp: 12:03
5. speed: 10; timestamp: 12:04
6. speed: 10; timestamp: 12:05
7. speed: 20; timestamp: 12:06
8. speed: 90; timestamp: 12:07
9. speed: 90; timestamp: 12:08
10. speed: 90; timestamp: 12:09

This is what I want:

running:

- 12:00
- 12:01
- 12:02
- 12:03

stopped:

- 12:04
- 12:05
- 12:06

running:

- 12:07
- 12:08
- 12:09

I haven't been able to come up with an elegant solution to this. This is what I have:

```
public class ListSortingTest {

    static List<Map<String, List<String>>> prodList = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> pts = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> npts = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pair<Integer, String>> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        messages.add(new ImmutablePair<Integer, String>(90, "12:00")); //p
        messages.add(new ImmutablePair<Integer, String>(80, "12:01")); //p
        messages.add(new ImmutablePair<Integer, String>(80, "12:02")); //p
        messages.add(new ImmutablePair<Integer, String>(90, "12:03")); //p
        messages.add(new ImmutablePair<Integer, String>(10, "12:04")); //np
        messages.add(new ImmutablePair<Integer, String>(10, "12:05")); //np
        messages.add(new ImmutablePair<Integer, String>(20, "12:06")); //np
        messages.add(new ImmutablePair<Integer, String>(90, "12:07")); //p
        messages.add(new ImmutablePair<Integer, String>(90, "12:08")); //p
        messages.add(new ImmutablePair<Integer, String>(90, "12:09")); //p

        int x = 0;
        for (Pair<Integer, String> message : messages) {
            if (message.getLeft() > 60) {
                pts.add(message.getRight());
                // check if end of array is reached + if next message has speed lower than threshold
                // so i know when to compile the list
                if (x++ == messages.size() - 1 || messages.get(x).getLeft() < 20) {
                    Map<String, List<String>> temp = new HashMap<>();
                    //copy so clear() doesn't remove list from temp
                    ArrayList<String> temparr = new ArrayList<String>(pts);
                    temp.put("p", temparr);
                    prodList.add(temp);
                    pts.clear();
                }
            } else {
                npts.add(message.getRight());
                if (x++ == messages.size() - 1 || messages.get(x).getLeft() > 20) {
                    Map<String, List<String>> temp = new HashMap<>();
                    //copy so clear() doesn't remove list from temp
                    ArrayList<String> temparr = new ArrayList<String>(npts);
                    temp.put("np", temparr);
                    prodList.add(temp);
                    npts.clear();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(prodList);
    }
}
```

This produces the right output:

```
[{p=[12:00, 12:01, 12:02, 12:03]}, {np=[12:04, 12:05, 12:06]}, {p=[12:07,   12:08, 12:09]}]
```

Can I do this in a more efficient way?

Comment: well, the body of the `if`s is basically the same, just using a different lists (and strings), so you could extract that part to a method taking a list and a String, which would reduce code duplication.

Comment: But what you really have here is a state machine with 2 states that you need to distinguish - no need to keep 2 Lists, really. A flag "isRunning" would be enough, or a `State`-enum of some kind. If the state changes, you add you intermediate results to the `prodList` and clear your intermediate( `temp`) results.

Comment: Also, I would try to avoid evaluating 2 elements in each iteration of the loop - it should be enough to "flush" the elements of you last state after the loop has completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 stream and then you code will be something like that

```
prodList = messages.stream()
        .collect(Collector.of(
            ArrayList::new,
            (accumulator, item) -> {
                if (accumulator.isEmpty()) {
                    accumulator.add(createNewMap(item));
                } else {
                    Map<String, List<String>> lastMap = accumulator.get(accumulator.size() - 1);
                    String keyMap = (new ArrayList<>(lastMap.keySet()).get(0));
                    if (keyMap.equals(getKeyStringValue(item))) {
                        List<String> items = lastMap.get(keyMap);
                        items.add(item.getValue());
                        lastMap.put(keyMap, items);
                    } else {
                        accumulator.add(createNewMap(item));
                    }
                }
            },
            (li1, li2) -> {
                li1.addAll(li2);
                return li1;
            }
        ));

private Map<String, List<String>> createNewMap(Pair<Integer, String> item) {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(item.getValue());
    map.put(getKeyStringValue(item), list);
    return map;
}

private String getKeyStringValue(Pair<Integer, String> item) {
    return item.getKey() > 20 ? "p" : "np";
}
```

And will see the similar output:

```
[{p=[12:00, 12:01, 12:02, 12:03]}, {np=[12:04, 12:05, 12:06]}, {p=[12:07, 12:08, 12:09]}]
```